# Conditionally Execute Routes in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Working towards implementing ACL in backbone.js, I was looking for a method to conditionally trigger routes based on the outcome of some function. Should I use execute or route ?

```js
function isRouteAuthorized(route, name) {
// returns true or false depending on some conditions
}

Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {"": "users", "resources": "resources",},
    route: function (route, name, callback) {
        if (isRouteAuthorized(route, name)) {
            //follow to route
            // How to achieve this ??
        } else {
            //go to error route
            // How to achieve this ??
        }

    },

    users: function () {
        //display users view
    },
    resources: function () {
        //display resources view
    },
    error: function () {
        //display error view
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `router.navigate()` method to use a different route. You'd need to pass `{trigger: true}` as an option to it so that it invokes the specified router method as well.

```js
Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {"": "users", "resources": "resources",},
    execute: function (callback, name, args) {
        if (condition) {
            //follow to route
            callback.apply(this, args);
        } else {
            //go to error route
            this.navigate('error', {trigger: true});
        }
        return false;
    },

    users: function () {
        //display users view
    },
    resources: function () {
        //display resources view
    },
    error: function () {
        //display error view
    }
});
```